# Hydrogen Peroxide 60% Dilution

Tags: hydrogen, chemical-formula

Can anyone please help me? I have used various 'dilution' calculators' online, and done the equations on paper. However I DO NOT want to get this wrong and one  can be great at math, but help and guidance when applying is wise.
I currently have one 250ml bottle of 60% ( yes 60) Hydrogen Peroxide. I would like to make up 2ltr volume of 6% and 2ltr, 1ltr & 500ml of 3% dilution. I would be most grateful if anyone can tell me (not ratios) exactly how many mls of H2O2 to how many mls of water to achieve those dilutions and volumes.
These solutions are for household purposes and Chem was never my field at high school all the many years ago.
Also how do I safely store it in my home? (living through an NZ hot summer)
Thank you Science People

Answer (score 1):

### Send the peroxide for destruction!

You are clearly not equipped for this with either competence or actual equipment. You cannot store this safely in your home. It autodecomposes and the stronger and hotter the peroxide is the larger chance you have a runaway reaction that ends in  an explosion. It spontaneously ignites fires in wood and other household items. It violently decomposes if contaminated. It will cause severe injuries to skin or eyes if they are exposed to it. I would **never** handle hydrogen peroxide above 30% if avoiding it is an option - **and I work as the site manager for a hydrogen peroxide factory!** I am one of the two contact persons for accidents involving hydrogen peroxide for my country.

Furthermore, I don't know about NZ, but here in the EU hydrogen peroxide is a bomb precursor and illegal to posess without license under **terrorism laws**. If you were european, I would have reported this question to an antiterror hotline (in fact, I would be obliged to do so, as per agreement with the authorities). You do not want to be investigated by the police on terrorism charges.

If you cannot dispose of it in any safe way, if you somehow are reluctant to deliver it to the police; here is as safe as I can suggest with household items: Find an **outside** stove, fill a kettle with 5 liters of water. Bring it to a boil, and slowly add peroxide little by little to the kettle. This should not take less than an hour. It can still hurt you badly, and you are on your own as far as liabilites go.

Comment: Thank you. It was sold in a local grocer so  as a civil should be able to assume that they were legally allowed. Will investigate disposal and legality.

Comment: fire department called. and the grocer has been reported

Comment: @Constnace Must be a grocer doing very well then indeed, all those spurious fires, maimed clerks and detonations in the peroxide aisle must be costly - but it seems to still be in operation.